# configuration files and ssh keys are being reset

Tags: linux, centos, httpd.conf, ssh-keys

I own a Centos 6.4 OS. I have standard lamp stack installed. Apache 2.2, PHP54 and mysql 5.5. I have also uploaded a public key into my authorized file in .ssh. I have my document root set in my httpd.conf. Everything works as it should. Until a couple days later or so when everything suddenly resets..

My ssh key is gone, my httpd.conf file is reset to its default state. Like I never configured anything. Does anyone have any idea why this might happen?

Comment: Is this a virtual server / VPS?

Comment: Yes. The host is digitalocean.

Answer (score 1):

There are two ways that this can occur:

### First way:

Someone has individually taken old copies of your configuration files, perhaps using a tool like etckeeper or simply pointing git at your config files, and inexplicably replaced new copies with the old ones. If this sounds ridiculous it's because it is.

### Second way:

Since you are using a virtual server form Digital Ocean, it seems most likely that your server was restored to a previous snapshot before your changes were made. If you did not do this yourself, then there may have been an error at your host that caused your virtual machine to restore to a previous snapshot. You'll need to take this up with them.